# How can I sum cost items, grouped by invoice?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two SQL Server tables below:

**Invoice**

```
InvoiceId     Amount    [Date]
        1         10    2015-05-28 21:47:50.000 
        2         20    2015-05-28 21:47:50.000
        3         25    2015-05-28 23:25:50.000
```

**InvoiceItem**

```
Id   InvoiceId   Cost
 1           1      8
 2           1      3
 3           1      7
 4           2     15
 5           2     17
 6           3     20
 7           3     22
```

Now I want to `JOIN` these two tables `ON` **InvoiceId** and retrieve the following:

1. `COUNT` of `DISTINCT` **InvoiceId** from **Invoice** table `AS` **[Count]**
2. `SUM` of **Amount** from **Invoice** table `AS` **Amount**
3. `SUM` of **Cost** from **InvoiceItem** table `AS` **Cost**
4. `HOUR` part of **[Date]**

and `GROUP` them `BY` `HOUR` part of **[Date]**.

Desired Output wil be:

```
  [Count]      Amount     Cost    HourOfDay
        2          30       50           22
        1          25       42           23
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you looked up GROUP BY?

Comment: `select datepart(HOUR, getdate())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one approach is to use a derived table:

```
   SELECT   CAST([Date] AS DATE) AS [Date],
            DATEPART(HOUR,i.[Date]) AS HourOfDay, 
            COUNT(i.InvoiceId) AS NumberOfInvoices,
            SUM(i.Amount) AS Amount,
            SUM(it.Cost) AS Cost
    FROM    invoice i
            INNER JOIN
            (SELECT InvoiceId, SUM(Cost) AS Cost
             FROM invoiceitem
             GROUP BY InvoiceId) it ON i.InvoiceId = it.InvoiceId 
    GROUP BY [Date],DATEPART(HOUR,i.[Date])
```

or a CTE (Common Table Expression)

```
WITH InvoiceCosts (InvoiceId, Cost)
AS
(
    SELECT InvoiceId, SUM(Cost) AS Cost
    FROM invoiceitem
    GROUP BY InvoiceId
)


SELECT  CAST([Date] AS DATE) AS [Date],
        DATEPART(HOUR,i.[Date]) AS HourOfDay, 
        COUNT(i.InvoiceId) AS NumberOfInvoices,
        SUM(i.Amount) AS Amount,
        SUM(ic.Cost) AS Cost
FROM    invoice i
        INNER JOIN
        InvoiceCosts ic ON i.InvoiceId = ic.InvoiceId 
GROUP BY [Date],DATEPART(HOUR,i.[Date])
```

Comment: If it's possible that invoices exists without entries in invoiceItem then use LEFT JOIN instead and SUM(ISNULL(it.Cost,0)) for the first query and SUM(ISNULL(ic.Cost,0)) for the CTE Version

Answer (score 0):

```
         SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT inv.InvoiceId) [Count],
                SUM (Amount) Amount,
                SUM (Cost) Cost,
                datepart(HOUR, inv.[Date]) HourOfDay
           FROM Invoice inv
     INNER JOIN InvoiceItem itm
             ON inv.InvoiceId = itm.InvoiceId
       GROUP BY datepart(HOUR, inv.[Date]);
```

Comment: does exactly what the user has asked in the simplest form but surely an inner join would be best instead of outer join (just for performance)

Comment: i stand corrected; as this is after all invoice data, there is no good technical or business reason to use OUTER JOIN. thanks.

Comment: This is wrong! You get wrong amount value! What's more: Ambigous Column Name "InvoiceId" -> you forgot the table alias in the first column

Comment: what about now? i fixed the column alias. my bad, i write this SQL in notepad. yet, i see nothing wrong with the Amount. can u explain in detail?

Comment: hey, @CeOnSql, what is with the down-vote? down-vote is for useless answer. i don't think my answer useless. i'm not interested to compete your answer anyway. your still the hero of this thread.

Comment: you get amounts 70 and 50, correct would be 30 and 25. Because you sum up 25 + 25 (for hour 23) and 10+10+10+20+20 (for hour 21)

Comment: please read it or read it again if u already have read it. http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior enjoy ur downvote.., i'm going home. (Y)